# zsh file tab completion: path preceded by non-space character

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I couldn't figure out a way to search for this and see if it is already explained on the Internet.

I have the following at the command line and I want to hit `<TAB>` at the end to start file completion:

```
   mycmd process file=data/old/1/
```

When I was using Bash, that TAB would show me the files in the folder `1/` but with Zsh that doesn't happen unless I enter a space after the `=` sign. Can I reconfigure Zsh to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
setopt magic_equal_subst
```

This works both with old-style and new-style completion, i.e. with or without `compinit`.

Completion of file names after `=` is an obscure and undocumented side effect of the [`magic_equal_subst`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-MAGIC_005fEQUAL_005fSUBST) option. The documented effect of this option is to enable [filename expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) after `=`.

Most of the time, if you notice the effect of this option at all, it's a desirable effect, e.g.

```
somecommand --option=~/file
```

passes a path under your home directory to `somecommand`, not a path in a directory called `~`. However, this also has the usually undesirable effect that an argument `==` triggers filename expansion:

```
somecommand foo==bar
```

passes `foo=/bin/bar` if the command `bar` is found in `$PATH` at `/bin/bar`. If you want to pass `==` literally to the command, at least one of the equal signs needs to be quoted, e.g.

```
somecommand foo=\=bar
somecommand foo\==bar
```

In the new-style completion system, this is handled inside [`_default`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Zsh/Context/_default). If you want to get filename completion after `=` without enabling `magic_equal_subst`, you need to override or wrap around `_default` to obtain the same effect. For example:

```
autoload +X -U _default
functions[_default]="setopt local_options magic_equal_subst; $functions[_default]"
```